# Cannot find module 'Socket.IO-node' when trying to run node.js boilerplate project

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm getting an error when I try to run a project created with the node.js boilerplate project I've installed socket.io using NPM with this command:

npm install socket.io

The error I'm getting is:

```
node.js:189
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'Socket.io-node'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mairead.buchan/Documents/WORK/auto-aggro/server.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:406:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:445:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:458:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:181:26)
```

My question is, do I either have some kind of incorrect combination of node/socket.io versions? (I know socket.io has just gone up to 0.7).

FYI I did a compile from source for node yesterday (using 5.0) and have installed everything else using NPM today so it should all be the running at the latest version

Is node.js boilerplate out of date with changes to the socket.io project?

or is there another way to specifically install socket.io-node that I can't find. All the answers seem to point to just installing socket.io.

Would love some advice. am a total noob, thanks

Comment: What does the source code in question look like? We can see the stacktrace, yes, but that tells us nothing about your actual code.

Comment: I believe there are issues with socket.io and node 5.0. Try 4.8

Comment: @jcolebrand - I have no code yet. I'm just installing the boilerplate code. I haven't created any application code. The stacktrace is coming from running a boilerplate project the first time without anything in it

Comment: @mairead that doesn't make any sense then. There must be _some_ code for it to compile and complain about. What URL did you download the project file from?

Comment: The boilerplate code is here: https://github.com/robrighter/node-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use the [latest stable build(0.4.9)](http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.9.tar.gz). I believe the 0.5.x branch has 
some API changes which is not compatible with socket.io(0.7.x).

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/socketio$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"

alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ node -v
v0.4.9
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ npm -v
1.0.15

alfred@alfred-laptop:~/node/socketio$ npm ls
/home/alfred
├── connect-redis@1.0.6 
├─┬ everyauth@0.2.15 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.5.2 
│ │ ├── connect-redis@1.0.6  extraneous
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ │ └── qs@0.2.0 
│ ├── oauth@0.9.2 
│ ├── openid@0.1.8 
│ ├── restler@0.2.1 
│ └─┬ xml2js@0.1.9 
│   └── sax@0.1.4 
├─┬ express@2.4.1 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.5.2 
│ │ ├── connect-redis@1.0.6  extraneous
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ │ └── qs@0.2.0 
│ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ └── qs@0.2.0 
├── hiredis@0.1.12 
├── jade@0.12.4 
├── notifo@0.0.2 
├── openid@0.2.0 
├── redis@0.6.6 
└─┬ socket.io@0.7.6 
  ├── policyfile@0.0.3 
  ├── redis@0.6.0 
  └── socket.io-client@0.7.3

alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ mkdir -p ~/tmp
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp$ cd ~/tmp
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp$ curl http://dl.dropbox.com/u/314941/socketio.tar.gz | tar xvz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 32752  100 32752    0     0  27122      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 40685
socketio/
socketio/public/
socketio/nodemon-ignore
socketio/.monitor
socketio/app.js
socketio/public/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
socketio/public/index.html
```

alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp$ node socketio/app.js 
   info  - socket.io started

```
google alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp$ google-chrome http://localhost:3000/
[23812:23829:31307528453:ERROR:io_thread.cc(120)] Invalid IP address specified for --dns-server: 
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

Works just for me. I think you should provide the same information(try my socket.io code specified in curl link).

Comment: updated my answer to give even more information. Could you please repeat steps. Some steps are not available in every os I think like `cat /etc/lsb-release`, but you should provide command approriate to your operating system.

Comment: I got as far as the curl statement then I got something pretty ugly. see below. I couldn't paste it in a comment

Comment: lol mairead, I piped curl => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(Unix). The command should be `curl http://dl.dropbox.com/u/314941/socketio.tar.gz | tar xvz` because I put my code inside an archive

Comment: ok, thanks for the help alfred. I definitely have socket.io up and running independently, so it must be a conflict somewhere in the boilerplate project. I guess that serves me right for trying to take a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.5 (10H574)
Kernel Version: Darwin 10.5.0


the-lambda-zone:node mairead.buchan$ node -v 
v0.4.9

the-lambda-zone:node mairead.buchan$ npm -v
1.0.15

/Users/mairead.buchan/Documents/WORK/node
├─┬ express@2.4.2 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.5.2 
│ │ └── connect-redis@1.0.6  extraneous
│ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ └── qs@0.2.0 
├── redis@0.6.6 
└─┬ socket.io@0.7.6 
  ├── policyfile@0.0.3 
  ├── redis@0.6.0 
  └── socket.io-client@0.7.3 

the-lambda-zone:node mairead.buchan$ mkdir -p ~/tmp
the-lambda-zone:node mairead.buchan$ cd ~/tmp
the-lambda-zone:tmp mairead.buchan$ curl http://dl.dropbox.com/u/314941/socketio.tar.gz
```